# How to share a site you've set up locally with the web

Tags: mysql, apache, localhost, mamp

I've recently set up a new site that runs a database via MAMP. It's actually an expression engine site and I'm developing it at localhost:8888.

I was wondering if there's an easy way to share the site with someone else over the web (like a client) via my IP address while my local server is running.

Not sure if there are security issues with this, but it would be easier than deploying it to a testing server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are behind a router, you'd need to forward incoming port `80` to your ip and locally  port `8888`.
2. Make sure that apache is not only availabe from localhost (use your networkip: `8888` to test)
3. Open port `8888` in your firewall (not always required)
4. Give your ip to your friends

Answer (score 1):

This can get complicated because (I presume) you're on a router. You need to forward a specific port to your computer and give out your IP address. If you're not up to scratch with security, I'd be careful when doing this. You'll also need to configure your router to accept connections on that port (8888).

I do this all the time on my local network, but I always use a testing server when I need to show clients.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like this is not worth the trouble and that I should just deploy to a testing server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the port in your router (assuming you are behind a router) and firewall(s). Then you need to setup NAT to forward port 8888 to the IP address of the computer behind the router that is running your webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your router. Most SOHO routers have an option to use dyndns and forward trafic to an internal host. If your router have these features, then:

- Register an address at a service like dyndns, lets say, "leemacalilly.dyndns.org"
- Redirect incoming trafic from the port 80 (www) to your internal host IP address, port 8888

See your router manual.